# How to dynamically change the view of a listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Google news app has this feature of show more on each of its news article (highlighted in the image below).

When the user clicks it the view of that listview item changes and show more details of the news.

I would like to know how can one respond to a click on a listview item and show a different view.

[image]

Comment: have you looked at `RecyclerView`? either way it looks like just an Expandable listview